# extract substring inside text from input and store the text inside folder/directory

Tags: javascript, php

I have a text area that does this when the image button is pressed:

[image: Image in textarea]

When the user "adds message" I need to find the strings in the text such that I can extract the url. For example `<img src="image.png">` I want to grab the `image.png` so that I can process it and store in a folder system.

**1. Regex to find location**

I will need to use some javascript here. I'll need to start at the first quote and end at the second quote. I'm struggling to find a way to do this without mistaking other quotes used in the text.

What I have tried:

```
function getIndicesOf(text) {
    
    var StartIndex = text.search("src=\"") + 5;
    var EndIndex = // not sure, maybe I can search for image extensions (png,jpeg) etc. 
    var imageAddress = text.substring(StartIndex,EndIndex);
    return imageAddress;
}
```

**2. Storing into folder**

I understand I believe, how to do this process when using an `<input type=file>`. However, in php can I replace the `$_FILE['image']['name']`  with `$imageAddress`

So instead of

```
<?php
$name = (isset($_POST['project_name']) ) ? $_POST['project_name'] : '';

$fixedPath = "projects_data/";

if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["project_image"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["project_image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["project_image"]["name"],
     "$fixedPath/$name/". $_FILES["project_image"]["name"]);
    echo "Stored in: " . "$fixedPath/$name/" . $_FILES["project_image"]["name"];
      }
?>
```

can I replace the `$_FILES['project_image']['name']` and do this:

```
<?php

$name = $imageAddress;
$fixedPath = "projects_data/";

if (file_exists("uploads/" . $imageAddress))
      {
      echo $imageAddress . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      
      move_uploaded_file($imageAddress,
     "$fixedPath/$name/". $imageAddress);
    echo "Stored in: " . "$fixedPath/$name/" . $imageAddress;
      }
?>
```

I hope I have provided enough information to help yo understand what I am trying to achieve. If I haven't then please let me know and I will edit it.

Thanks.

Comment: add form code and script how you processing if image button clicked.

Comment: @Tausif It shouldn't matter, the javascript is the issue